# Cannot run internet search scripts from Xfce keyboard shortcuts

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, script, search, xfce

I have created different scripts that I successfully used under Lubuntu/Lxde, including some made to be run by keyboard shortcut that would start firefox and search selected text on the internet.

For example, this script, if associated with a shortcut, should search selected text in google:

```
#! bin/sh

sh -c 'firefox "https://www.google.com/search?q='$'(xclip -o)"'
```

One to translate French to English:

```
#! bin/sh

sh -c 'firefox "http://translate.google.com/#fr/en/$(xclip -o)"'
```

and so on

But in Mint/Xfce, cannot add these scripts to be run by shortcut in Settings/Keyboard/Application Shortcuts: I get an error similar to this:

[image]

I think some applications have to be installed to run this. But after installing `xclip` and `git` it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have a wrong shebang line, is that a typo? It should be `#!/bin/sh`. Also,please show the output of `ls -l /home/cipricus/Documents/scripts/firefox/search-google.sh`.

Comment: @terdon: the output:`$ ls -l /home/cipricus/Documents/scripts/firefox/search-google.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 cipricus cipricus 75 Nov 29 20:09 /home/cipricus/Documents/scripts/firefox/search-google.sh
`. the form of the script works fine, maybe something wrong with my copy/paste here?

Comment: And the shebang line?

Comment: don't know exactly what you say it's wrong. you say: "It should be #!/bin/sh". you mean no space between `!` and `/`? i just open my otherwise working scripts and pasted here

Comment: More importantly, I mean it should _have_ an `/`. In your question you have it as `#! bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: i was sure those scripts were working as posted an lubuntu! but you are completely right! post as answer please for the record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, I am posting my comment as an answer.

It looks like you have a bad [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line. Try

```
#!/bin/bash
```

instead of

```
#! bin/bash
```

The space should not be an issue, the `/` before `bash`, however, is essential.